# ExpressJS and passing variables between separate route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJs with Node.js and have put all my routes into a 'routes' folder.

On the server, I do my DB connection, then define my routes, like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes');

var db;
dbconnect = new mongo.Db(config.mongo_database, new mongo.Server(config.mongo_host, config.mongo_port, {}), {});
dbconnect.open(function (err, db) {

  db.authenticate(config.mongo_user, config.mongo_pass, function (err, success) {
    if (success) {

      //routes/index.js
      app.get('/', routes.index);

      //routes/users.js
      app.get('/users', routes.users);

    }
  });
});
```

I want to access the 'db' object inside each of these routes javascript files.  How would I pass that from this 'app.js' file to the index.js or users.js?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion is to expose your routes via a function which accepts a `db` parameter:

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    return {
        index: function(req, res, next) {
            // Funky db get stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Wrapping values in a closure like this and returning an object with more functions is a useful pattern, sometimes called "Revealing Module Pattern". It shows the dependencies clearly, allowing for easy testing (using e.g. a mock db object) while still using a flexible functional approach.

Comment: The drawback is now everytime you want to reuse a "module" across controllers, you have to add it to the signature, and you may end up with situations where some controllers need 2, some need 3, and one needs 5, and now you've got a signature that has to accomodate the greatest common denominator.  A better approach I think would be to encapsulate your db behavior in a loosely coupled module of it's own.

Comment: @BradHarris: That's definitely a drawback. One way to keep the same signature, if you feel that's important, is to accept an object with parameters instead: `{db: db, foo: foo, bar: bar}`. Your solution is definitely not a bad way to solve it, though it comes with drawbacks of it's own -- it's harder to unit test, for one.

Answer (score 13):

If you write your database abstraction in it's own file/module, you can then reuse it throughout your codebase as needed by just require()'ing it where needed.  It won't get re-created if you write it correctly, and can just get initialized once on application startup like your example does.

```
//contents of your database.js file
var database;

module.exports = {

    init : function(config, cb) {
        database = new mongo.Db(config.mongo_database, new mongo.Server(config.mongo_host, config.mongo_port, {}), {});
        database.open(function (err, db) {  
            db.authenticate(config.mongo_user, config.mongo_pass, cb);
        });
    },

    query : function(params, cb) {
        database.query(params, cb);
    }   

};
```

This is a trivial example, but hopefully it gets the point across.  In controllers or any files where you need that database object, you just...

```
var db = require('database');

db.init(params, function(err, db) {
    ...
});


db.query(params, function(err, db) {
    ...
});
```

The benefits are you now have a loosely coupled database object that can be used anywhere in your application just like any other node module through the require statement.

Comment: I like this. Another useful pattern is to have an object that represents your application (or application resources) as an object. E.g.  require('./myapp.js').db  or require('./myapp.js').config